# MahApps Metro DialogBox not showing text and background

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mahapps.metro

I have this `WPF` (`MVVM`) application where I'm using `MahApps`, where I have :

- The `Client` Project (basically the main WPF project)
- `Helpers` Project
- `Styling` Project

In the Helpers project I have `Helper` class that fires the `ShowMessageAsync` methods for me :

```
public static class ShowMessageBox
{
    public static async Task Show(MetroWindow metroWindow, string titre, string errorMessage, string errorDetails, string errorHelpLink)
    {

        var mySettings = new MetroDialogSettings()
        {
            AffirmativeButtonText = "Ok",
            NegativeButtonText = "Annuler",
            ColorScheme = MetroDialogColorScheme.Accented,
            AnimateShow = true,
            AnimateHide = true
        };
        await metroWindow.ShowMessageAsync(titre, string.Format(errorMessage + " ! \n {0} ... \n {1}",
                                           errorDetails, errorHelpLink), MessageDialogStyle.Affirmative, mySettings);
    }
 //...
```

In the Styling Project I call the MahApps resources in a `MahApps.xaml` file  :

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/orange.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/baselight.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

And I reference that from my `App.Xaml` hence :

```
<Application.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary>
        <valueConverters:ContentLengthToInvertedBooleanConverter x:Key="ContentLengthToInvertedBooleanConverter" />
        <valueConverters:ContentLengthToBooleanConverter x:Key="ContentLengthToBooleanConverter" />
        <viewModels:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
        <valueConverters:ListToIsEnabledConverter x:Key="ListToIsEnabledConverter" />
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Styling;component/MahApps.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Styling;component/Styles.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Styling;component/Brushes.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Styling;component/Assets/Assets.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
```

When I fire a the `MessageDialog` (in a certain ViewModel) :

```
var mainWindow = (MetroWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
await ShowMessageBox.Show(mainWindow, "Ajout !",
                    "Marque Ajoutée avec succés !", String.Empty, String.Empty,
                    0);
```

Here's what I get :

[image]

All what I get is that little `Ok` button that follows the accent correctly, but no White background, no text, no anything else. Note that I'm referencing MahApps.Metro in each project, What's wrong ? How can I correct this ??

Comment: This seems like a bug. Have you tried removing the metro reference and adding it again through NuGet?

Comment: Tried everything, clean, build, rebuild, close/reopen VisualStudio, reference the packages ... but no result ...

Comment: @AymenDaoudi Please test this with the latest alpha (also available via NuGet) again. If this is still present I would suggest you to create an issue at MahApps GitHub site, thx.

Comment: Perhaps the UI thread is busy doing something else. That might explain why the message is not shown. That was my issue.